How to make FCM Notification show as Banner when app in BG or killed on Android Client?
This is not a debugging question.
I will start with the over-arching question:
What exact configuration parameter/s is/are required in order for FCM messages to display a banner when the Android app is either backgrounded or killed?
In my research I have concluded that the answer lies either in:

A) the FCM message JSON definition (see below),
B) The Flutter code
(ie. FCM.instance.makeAndroidShowBannerInBackground(true), or
C) custom native Android Configuration such as creating custom message
channels.

In a Flutter+Firebase app that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), I have a cloud function that defines a message in the following way ("normal" Javascript, v1 function):
const multicastMessage = {
      tokens: tokens, // Array of tokens
      notification: {
        title: `Alert from ${userName}`,
        body: notificationBody, 
      },
      android: {
        priority: "high", // High priority for Android notifications
        ttl: 60, // TTL of 60 seconds (~1 minute)
        notification: {
          sound: "custom_notification_sound_alert",
        },
      },
      apns: {
        headers: {
          "apns-priority": "10", // High priority for APNs
          // Expires in 60 seconds
          "apns-expiration": `${Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60}`,
        },
        payload: {
          aps: {
            "alert": {
              title: `Alert from ${userName}`,
              body: notificationBody,
            },
            "sound": "CustomNotificationSoundAlert.wav",
          },
        },
      },
    };

As stated this is not a debugging question and "more code" should not be required if you understand that the message is delivered to both Android and IOS clients and seems to be working is every way except for one thing -- on Android, when the app is in the background or killed, the notification is delivered to the system tray as a tiny icon -- it does not appear as a banner on top of everything else.
Things I have tried:
General Google search yielding this github issue... but it is old am I am not confident that it still applies.
Firebase FCM documentation... while there are many related topics, the docs don't seem to directly/precisely acknowledge this (Android showing banner vs not when backgrounded/killed and why) as a potential issue.  While I have read a lot of it, I have not read all the docs, partly because I'm not sure in what section the answer would lie -- Android, Flutter, "Server"... and FCM is complex and concepts already get conflated easily enough in my mind.
I am not wanting to believe that the answer lies in (C) -- custom Android code configuration (such as defining custom message channels) because I thought the point of FCM was to be a wrapper... but this part of the Firebase Android SDK/FCM (Java) source code does make it seem that way:
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
          new NotificationChannel(
              // channel id
              FCM_FALLBACK_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL,
              // user visible name of the channel
              defaultChannelName,
              // shows everywhere, makes noise, but does not visually intrude.
              NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT));

Specifically, the ".IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT" and comment "shows everywhere, makes noise, but does not visually intrude." are interesting and may offer a clue.
But if it is true that there is only one "default" channel that is not high enough priority to show a banner, and I need to create a custom channel in native Android code... then why is there an Android priority key at all in the JSON?  And why can't there be an additional "default" channel (high priority) created by the SDK that correlates to the priority set in the JSON? :S
Maybe it's just something silly like the high in "priority: "high"" needs to be UPPERCASE?

I think you go on the right path
In my situation, my solution is like below.
First I make an android notification channel with value IMPORTANCE_HIGH. You can use native code or Flutter with your choice
Native like your code above
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
          new NotificationChannel(
              // channel id
              FCM_FALLBACK_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL,
              // user visible name of the channel
              defaultChannelName,
              // shows everywhere, makes noise, but does not visually intrude.
              NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH));

or you can use package flutter_local_notifications to help you make new channel

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
   var androidNotificationChannel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      "your_custom_channel_id",
      "your_custom_channel_name",
      importance: Importance.high,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(androidNotificationChannel);
}

Second when you push notification, you must push through your custom channel and it will work like a charm
const multicastMessage = {
      tokens: tokens, // Array of tokens
      notification: {
        title: `Alert from ${userName}`,
        body: notificationBody, 
      },
      android: {
        ttl: 60, 
        notification: {
          channel_id: "your_custom_channel_id" // Add this line for push through your channel id
          sound: "custom_notification_sound_alert",
        },
      },
      apns: {
        headers: {
          "apns-priority": "10", // High priority for APNs
          // Expires in 60 seconds
          "apns-expiration": `${Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60}`,
        },
        payload: {
          aps: {
            "alert": {
              title: `Alert from ${userName}`,
              body: notificationBody,
            },
            "sound": "CustomNotificationSoundAlert.wav",
          },
        },
      },
    };

